# Is there any preexisting extension for enumerable that makes it NullReferenceException safe?

Tags: c#, linq

I replaced the following code

```
if (myEnumerable != null)
{
 myEnumerable
   .Where(o => o.Somehing == something)
   .Select(o => o.SomeOtherThing);
}
```

With

```
myEnumerable
 .EmptyIfNull()
 .Where(o => o.Somehing == something)
 .Select(o => o.SomeOtherThing);
```

But the above was only possible because I rolled my own `EmptyIfNull`

```
public static IEnumerable<TElement> EmptyIfNull<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement source)
{
 return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<TElement>();
}
```

My question is, isn't there something of this sort already written with LINQ extensions that is same of a syntactic sugar? (Without the use of C# 6.0)

Comment: use null conditional operator `myEnumerable?.Where(o => o.Somehing == something).Select(o => o.SomeOtherThing);`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Does not compile

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: in that case i dont think there is any built in method or feature (ignoring C# 6) to achieve this but you can simplify `return source == null? Enumerable.Empty<TElement>() : source;` to this one: `return source ??  Enumerable.Empty<TElement>();`

Comment: I believe you should drop this Q&A... you know there's no built-in solution until C# 6 ;)

Comment: I know not the same and only a comment but for one you can use FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a standard extension like this, most probably because returning/passing null enumerables is considered a bad practice.
In [C#6 (VS2015)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators) you can use the following sugar

```
var q = myEnumerable?
 .Where(o => o.Somehing == something)
 .Select(o => o.SomeOtherThing);
```

but note that the result `q` in this case will be `null`, compared to empty enumerable in yours.

**Edit** Since you edited your question and put additional constraint, forget about `?.` operator - it doesn't produce equivalent result anyway (as I mentioned). But that doesn't change the primary answer at the beginning

> There **isn't** a standard extension like this

Comment: read the last words in question :) .((Without the use of C# 6.0))

Comment: well, it wasnt' there when I was writing the answer.